# How do I make use of the Drop Down Picker in react native expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My code:

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth)
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <Text>What cusine would you like to eat today?</Text>
      <DropDownPicker
          items={[
              {label: 'English', value: 'en'},
              {label: 'Deutsch', value: 'de'},
              {label: 'French', value: 'fr'},
          ]}
          defaultIndex={0}
          containerStyle={{height: 40}}
          onChangeItem={item => console.log(item.label, item.value)}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={handleSignOut}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  )
}
```

I am using https://snack.expo.dev/a6rDxpeU_ as reference. The drop down picker is suppose to look like:
[image]

But I got nothing on my screen though. There is no error or warning from the expo app or my terminal
My screen looks like:
[image]

Or am I doing something wrong here? I have done the import which is `import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'` and before the import, I have done the installation in my root folder which is `npm install react-native-dropdown-picker` from https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs. I also checked that under my package.json, I have the following dependencies: [image]

I have tried to pass the data that is selected in the drop down picker via https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C01CJlu7Q-I

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
             {label: 'Japanese', value: 'J'},                  
             {label: 'Korean', value: 'K'},
             {label: 'Western', value: 'F'},
             {label:'Indonesian', value:'I'},
             {label: 'Taiwan', value: 'T'},
             {label:'Chinese', value:'C'},
            ]);
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth)
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
  
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <Text>What cusine would you like to eat today?</Text>
      <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SubScreen1", {paramKey:items})}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={handleSignOut}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  )
}
```

But when i clicked the search button, it is not jumping to the next page. I assume its something wrong with the passing of the key. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it plz. Hope it would work.

```
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
```

```
function HomeScreen() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
             {label: 'English', value: 'en'},                  
             {label: 'Deutsch', value: 'de'},
             {label: 'French', value: 'fr'},
               ]);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
  );
}
```

You may found this useful:
[React native: Dropdown-link](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-native-picker-select/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it work perfectly! May I ask is the website I have referred to wrong? It is for react native though. This is my first time using react native expo so sorry for the novice question. I have tried to re - run my code and this time there is the box but cannot click at all.

Comment: No, your referred website is for react native. State [open, value, items] was not.  defined in the function(to store data); that's why it is not working. Thanks

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the explanation. May I ask how do i transfer this selection to another page?

Comment: ```<ExpectedComponent date={date}></ExpectedComponent>}``` ```https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-other-component-in-react-cbbafc755995```This  may help you.

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. As I am still unsure of that method, i tried another via a youtube guide. And it didnt work. Is it possible to help me see what is wrong? I have updated the post with what I did.